# Setting up HTML page on port 8083 in NGINX

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, port, portforwarding

I have been given a task in which I have to host an HTML page on port 8083. Now when I was followinf the steps of installing NGINX from [this](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-nginx#4-setting-up-virtual-host) page there was this piece of code:

```
server {
   listen 81;
   listen [::]:81;

   server_name example.ubuntu.com;

   root /var/www/tutorial;
   index index.html;

   location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
}
```

My question is that if I replace `80` with `8083` will it do the trick and if yes then how can I check it?